# Simple pivot on text values. Why is it so hard to find?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to pivot a table with two text columns, but it seems impossible to find a simple answer.

Nothing I've read helps, since it always assumes one or more columns will show values, and I only have text.

My table looks like this:

```
Name           Duties  
-------------------------                                                      
Mike           Cleaning  
Mike           Mopping
Mike           Washing
Mike           Gardening
Mike           Playing                                 
John           Cleaning                                                 
John           Washing                                                  
Tom            Cleaning
```

How can I get something that looks like this:

```
Name           Duty1       Duty2       Duty3      Duty4      Duty5        
---------------------------------------------------------------------
Mike           Cleaning    Mopping     Washing    Gardening  Playing        
John           Cleaning    Washing     NULL       NULL       NULL         
Tom            Cleaning    NULL        NULL       NULL       NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that uses window functions and conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN duties END) Duty1,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 2 THEN duties END) Duty2,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 3 THEN duties END) Duty3,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 4 THEN duties END) Duty4,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 5 THEN duties END) Duty5
FROM (
    SELECT 
        name, 
        duties, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY duties) rn
    FROM mytable
) x
GROUP BY name
ORDER BY name
```

This will order the duty columns alphabetically and handle up to 5 duties. If you have a column in the table that can be used to order the records (that you did not show in your sample data), then can change the ordering clause of the window function to use it. If you need to handle more than 5 duties per name, then you can add more `MAX(CASE ...)` expressions in the `SELECT` clause.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/rVZEMyg8f4RJmRbrjuEzfg/1)**:

```
| name | Duty1    | Duty2     | Duty3   | Duty4   | Duty5   |
| ---- | -------- | --------- | ------- | ------- | ------- |
| John | Cleaning | Washing   |         |         |         |
| Mike | Cleaning | Gardening | Mopping | Playing | Washing |
| Tom  | Cleaning |           |         |         |         |
```

Comment: it almost works! however, it shows them in alphabetical order, which is not the correct one. For example, it should show, for Mike: Cleaning, Mopping, Washing, Gardening, Playing. But it shows: Cleaning, Gardening, Mopping, Playing, Washing.

Comment: is there some way so it doesn't order them alphabetically?

Comment: @Incompetent77: yes, you can use another column from the table to order the duty columns in the resultset, as explained in my answer.

Comment: Got it! I added a row_num to them and that did the trick. thanks! i searched for hours and nothing, until you solved it. Thanks again!

Comment: @Incompetent77 mark the answer as correct if you you think it solves your question

Answer (score 0):

Another hacky alternative using `CHOOSE`. This also takes care of the ordering.

```
SELECT 
Name, 
MAX(CHOOSE(rn-0, Duties)) Duty1,
MAX(CHOOSE(rn-1, Duties)) Duty2,
MAX(CHOOSE(rn-2, Duties)) Duty3,
MAX(CHOOSE(rn-3, Duties)) Duty4,
MAX(CHOOSE(rn-4, Duties)) Duty5
FROM 
(SELECT Name, Duties, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Name ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) rn FROM mytable) x 
GROUP BY Name
ORDER BY Name;
```